# Not understandable behavior of the append() function in R

Tags: r, vector

I am trying to create a list of vectors in R. Using the following code:

```
companies <- list("AAPL", "MSFT")

columns <- list()

for (company in companies)
{
  column <- c(get_price(company), get_balance_sheet_data(company), get_ebit(company))
  columns <- append(columns, column)
}
```

Each of the "get_x" functions returns a vector with double(s) as values. I want the "column" variable to be a vector that contains all of the values from sub-vectors and then append that vector to the list called "columns". This, however, returns a list as shown below:

```
[[1]]
[1] 164.66

[[2]]
[1] 352755000

[[3]]
[1] 302083000

[[4]]
[1] 50672000

[[5]]
[1] 149631000

[[6]]
[1] 50672000

[[7]]
[1] 50672000

[[8]]
[1] -18577000

[[9]]
[1] 170741000

[[10]]
[1] 50672000

[[11]]
[1] 120069000

[[12]]
[1] 96423000

[[13]]
[1] 15943425

[[14]]
[1] 15943425

[[15]]
[1] 122034000

[[16]]
[1] 291.6

[[17]]
[1] 364840000

[[18]]
[1] 198298000

[[19]]
[1] 166542000

[[20]]
[1] 213574000

[[21]]
[1] 166542000

[[22]]
[1] 11489000

[[23]]
[1] 87720000

[[24]]
[1] 74602000

[[25]]
[1] 216323000

[[26]]
[1] 87720000

[[27]]
[1] 61270000

[[28]]
[1] 35850000

[[29]]
[1] 7464000

[[30]]
[1] 85779000
```

What I want is a list that on index 1 contains a vector for "AAPL", on the second index a vector for "MSFT", and so on. How can I solve that?

Thanks!

I tried using multiple functions that append vectors to a list but nothing helped. I also converted all of the functions that previously returned a double to return a vector with a single value inside (so that all functions return the same datatype - vectors) but it did not help.

Comment: It would be better to mention the package used

Answer (score 2):

Instead of initializing and then `append`ing in a `for` loop, it can be done more easily with `lapply` which returns a `list` of vectors.

```
companies <- list(AAPL = "AAPL", MSFT = "MSFT")
out <- lapply(companies, \(x) c(get_price(x), 
       get_balance_sheet_data(x), get_ebit(x)))
```

---

Regarding the issue in the post, `append` does what it is asked to do i.e. it appends the elements to the `list`.  Here, `column` is a vector of length 3, which gets appended as 3 individual new entries in the columns.  e.g.

```
> append(list(), c(1, 2, 3))
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3
```

Using the `for` loop,

```
> columns <- list()
> for(i in 1:5) {column <- c(i, i, i); columns <- append(columns, column)}
```

Instead, we may need to wrap the `column` output in a `list` to contain the vector as a single unit.  Now, it should work fine

```
> columns <- list()
> for(i in 1:5) {column <- list(c(i, i, i)); columns <- append(columns, column)}
```

-output

```
> columns
[[1]]
[1] 1 1 1

[[2]]
[1] 2 2 2

[[3]]
[1] 3 3 3

[[4]]
[1] 4 4 4

[[5]]
[1] 5 5 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Another take on akrun's answer is to generate the output from `lapply()` as a list of data frames that can subsequently be combined with `rbind()`.

companies <- list(AAPL = "AAPL", MSFT = "MSFT")

```
set.seed(10317008)
out <- lapply(companies,function(x){
   data.frame(company = x,
              price = rnorm(1,500,45),
              balance_sheet_item = rnorm(1,20000,75),
              ebit = rnorm(1,2000000,30000000)) 
})

do.call(rbind,out)
```

...and the output:

```
> do.call(rbind,out )
     company    price balance_sheet_item     ebit
AAPL    AAPL 471.8496           19933.06 13230143
MSFT    MSFT 423.7655           19985.90 10544019
>
```